# in R, elastic net missing class in classification model

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

In the cousera.org Machine Learning course assignment project, I adopt elastic net model to find the best classification model.

The training and testing data are compared to find what should be kept as training. I have checked NAs and highly correlated variables.

Data x is the training data, y is the variable "classe" in the train data. after removing highly correlated variables of x, 20 has been eliminated, which contains 32 numeric and no NAs variables. 
Data y are factor "A"~"E".

```
elastic_model<-train(y=y,x=x,method="glmnet",trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),tuneLength=10)
```

above model got:

```
 elastic_model$bestTune

  alpha     lambda

1    0.1        0.01217372

coef(elastic_model$finalModel,s=elastic_model$bestTune$lambda)
```

Above may give the results of all A~E classes, I can see some variables may be removed.

but below prediction give wrong results:

```
 predictions <- predict(elastic_model,testData)

 table(predictions,testData$classe)

predictions    A    B    C    D    E

          A  108   47   19   16   37

          B   12   82    0   25   41

          C 1121  606  758  233  472

          D  433  404  249  690  532

          E    0    0    0    0    0
```

in the predictions, class E is lost totally.  I can't find the reason.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with. You can use `dput` for data.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved the problem by scaling the data.